# Nodejs execSync works but not working, change to sytem not taking effect

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell

I want to block **chrome.exe** in **windows firewall**. The command for accomplishing the task is

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block Chrome" dir=out action=block program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" enable=yes'
```

Above command works fine when issued via **PowerShell**. But when I tries to do this
in **Nodejs**

```js
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync,  

    command = 'netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block Chrome" dir=out action=block program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" enable=yes'

const result = execSync( command )

console.log( result )
```

It prints

```
Ok.
```

By output, I am assuming that command is getting executed. But **Chrome** is not getting affected by that. It can still access the internet.

When I run the same command in **PowerShell**, it blocks chrome immediately. I am wondering why running the command on **Nodejs** is not working as expected?

Given that **Nodejs has Administrator Rights**, what can be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape backslashes:

```js
    command = 'netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Block Chrome" dir=out action=block program="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" enable=yes'
```

Comment: It worked, but please explain, so fellow readers can get best out of this answer

Comment: A backslash is used for escaping in JS strings. If you do not escape it in the Windows path, it just means "escape the next character", which is no-op in most cases with not reserved characters. If you evaluate the path part of your string command in a console, you can see what it means for the parser: `' program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" '` becomes `' program="C:Program Files (x86)GoogleChromeApplicationchrome.exe" '`.

Comment: I understand that, but look it got same output, and that what confusing me. If command becomes wrong then output must be some error rather than Ok.

Comment: Do you get any errors if you run your command in the powershell with the `program="C:Program Files (x86)GoogleChromeApplicationchrome.exe"` part?

Comment: I said that JavaScript code given in question is working fine in node and execSync() returning Ok. Why it is giving right output if it is escaping characters? This is the crux. Can you explain this?

Comment: Neither JavaScript engine nor Node.js know if you use backslashes as escape characters or just misuse them. It is valid syntax and it is handled as is. It seems for `netsh` program the path `"C:Program Files (x86)GoogleChromeApplicationchrome.exe"` also seems valid somehow, so you do not get any errors in the received output. But this path does not match with the Chrome process path, so blocking does not work.